# Persian Calendar Python

Tags: python, datetime, jalali-calendar

Why is the output of this code true? What are your alternatives for this?

```
from khayyam import *

print(JalaliDate(1389, 2, 18) == JalaliDate(1391, 12, 30))



True
```

Comment: This is a bug in the library. I'm reporting it now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report for a python package.